# Simple OpenGL / GLSL program does not work

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, pyside, pyopengl

**Question:** What is wrong with this simple OpenGL/GLSL program?
It is supposed to produce a quad with a red-green color gradient.
But I just get a black window, and no error messages.

```
import numpy
from OpenGL.GL import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtOpenGL import *

_vertexShaderSource = (
    'attribute vec2 a_position;'
    'attribute vec3 a_color;'
    'varying vec3 v_color;'
    ''
    'void main()'
    '{'
    '   gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);'
    '   v_color = a_color;'
    '}'
)

_fragmentShaderSource = (
    'varying vec3 v_color;'
    ''
    'void main()'
    '{'
    '    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color, 1.0);'
    '}'
)

_POSITION = 0
_COLOR = 1

class HelloWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self._shaderProgram = QGLShaderProgram(self.context())
        self._shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Vertex, _vertexShaderSource)
        self._shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader.Fragment, _fragmentShaderSource)
        self._shaderProgram.link()
        self._shaderProgram.bind()

        glBindAttribLocation(self._shaderProgram.programId(), _POSITION, 'a_position')
        glBindAttribLocation(self._shaderProgram.programId(), _COLOR, 'a_color')

    def paintGL(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        position = numpy.ndarray([-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5], numpy.float32)
        glVertexAttribPointer(_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, position)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(_POSITION)

        color = numpy.ndarray([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], numpy.float32)
        glVertexAttribPointer(_COLOR, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, color)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(_COLOR)

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = HelloWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**Answer:** There are two bugs in the code.

1. The calls to `glBindAttribLocation` must come before `self._shaderProgram.link()`, as pointed out by Brett Hale.
2. `numpy.ndarray` should be replaced by `numpy.array`.

If you fix these two problems, then the code works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man page for `glBindAttribLocation`:](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation)

> Any attribute binding that occurs after the program object has been
>          linked will not take effect until the next time the program object is
>          linked.

Associate the attribute indices first, *then* link the program.

Alternatively, assign a value to `_POSITION`, `_COLOR`, etc., using `glGetAttribLocation`.

---

As @KillianDS mentions, you can specify the index (location) in the shader, provided you have GL 3.3 or above. This is a source of frustration on OS X, which only *guarantees* GL 3.2.

---

It might also be worth pointing out that `GL_QUADS` is not supported in the core profile, so it may be necessary to work around that, e.g., with 2 triangles.

Comment: or even better, just use fixed locations with `layout(location = i)`, in the end this usually saves you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have posted a comment, but it got long. Hopefully this helps you:

Since your using the `attribute` keyword (a compatibility keyword) in your vertex shader, could you clarify what version of OpenGL and GLSL you are using? I don't see anything referring to the version in your code; did I miss it? It may help a bit to understand what the issue is.

The `layout` formatting would certainly simplify things if you have it available. <strike>Also, your shader(s) requires it's `#version` to be specified (at least in the [latest spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.30.7.pdf), though I think it holds for all versions).</strike> Not necessary for 1.10 (though still supported), which the OP is using/intends to use.

Comment: I'm testing the code on a machine that runs OpenGL 3.3. We will probably target OpenGL 2.0. (Currently all our products are written with OpenGL 1.5. Many of our customers have old Intel graphics cards. But we are thinking of moving to OpenGL 2.0.)

Comment: Well, assuming OpenGL 2.0, shader version 1.1, you won't have `layout` available. I don't have much time at the posting of this comment, but i'll double check if there's anything about your code that conflicts with the [OpenGL 2.0 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec20.20041022.pdf) and the [GLSL 1.1 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf) in a few hours. Also, you don't _need_ the `#version 110` directive for  shader version 1.10, as it is the default. Given this, I don't see any issues at the moment.

Comment: @user763305 Also, have you thrown in some `glGetError` calls, or have you checked your shader/program for compiling/linking errors?

Comment: QtOpenGL and  PyOpenGl check for errors automatically. There is no need to call `glGetError`.

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems like you're mixing modern and legacy"? I've tried to keep everything OpenGL 2.0 / GLSL 1.10.

Comment: That was my own misinterpretation, i'll edit that out. When looking through other people's comments they were mentioning `layout` and other such things, so I thought you were using those or were using things from a newer version of OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Qt under Python but I'm pretty sure that you need to set your shader program as active using `glUseProgram`.

Comment: The line `self._shaderProgram.bind()` activates the shader program. See http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qglshaderprogram.html#bind.